# Excel Macro YesNo message box, different directions for Yes and No

Tags: vba, excel

The user has two options in the YesNo Message Box.  If No, it performs a certain sequence of filters, but I want to filter another column if the user answers Yes to the message box question.  Currently, at "Else", I get an error that reads "Compile error: Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object" If I take out "Else", and the code after it, the macro runs smoothly, but only filters when the user selects No.

```
If MsgBox("Is This Item Catch Weight?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    retval = InputBox("Please Enter PO Cost")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=71,         Criteria1:="=" & retval
    retval = InputBox("Please Enter Net Weight")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:="=" & retval
Else: MsgBox("Is This Item Catch Weight?", vbYesNo) = vbYes
    retval = InputBox("Please Enter PO Cost")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=71, Criteria1:="=" & retval
End If
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things are happening here. `:` new line character in VBA code so a line like

```
Else: MsgBox("Is This Item Catch Weight?", vbYesNo) = vbYes
```

is actually the same as

```
Else
   MsgBox("Is This Item Catch Weight?", vbYesNo) = vbYes
```

Which is not what you want.

There is also an extra `End If` at the end. Remove that.

Calling the message box to appear multiple times is probably not what oyu want either. Likely you want to show the message box, get the result then do something with it.

```
Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
response = MsgBox("Is This Item Catch Weight?", vbYesNo)
If response = vbNo Then
    'do stuff for yes
ElseIf response = vbYes Then
    ' do stuff for No
End If
```

I'd also suggest not using `ActiveSheet` unless you are sure that's what you want.